# Row with Expanded

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 3 widgets in the row

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Description",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.orange),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              descriptionText,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: const Color(0xff0000ff)),
            ),
          ),
          Text(">", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black))
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

The UI looked like this

[image]

How can I move the `All`  beside `>` ? If the text is too long, I would like the Text displayed multi line, that why I use `Expanded`.

Comment: You are already using `Spacer`, why don't you just remove `Expanded`?

Comment: @DimaRostopira If text too long, I want make it multiline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `Expanded`, however if there's a need for that, you can use the `textAlign` property:

```dart
Expanded(
  child: Text(
    'All',
    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
  ),
)
```

---

Full solution:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Description",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.orange),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              descriptionText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right, // <-- You need this
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: const Color(0xff0000ff)),
            ),
          ),
          Text(">", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black))
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```